# ruby const_missing method mystery

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I am playing with this piece of code, purely for studying ruby object model and const lookup.

```
class TestClass

  def self.const_missing(name)
    binding.pry
    super const_missing(name)
  end

  def self.do
    self.class_eval "puts 800; UNKOWNCONST"
  end

end

TestClass.do
```

Since the class_eval is done inside the class so 'UNKOWNCONST' will trigger the const_missing defined for above which lives in the singleton class of TestClass object, since its a class method.

So i intent to just delegate it to the normal const_missing method however I ended up with an error saying stack too deep. The binding.pry reveals that it goes into an infinite loop of going into the const_missing method I defined for my class, not to the normal const_missing method.

I am wondering why? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the following line:

```
super const_missing(name)
```

Here you have two statements:

- `super` is expected to call the method defined in the super class with the same name of the current method
- `const_missing(name)` which calls `const_missing`

The proper way to call the parent is just to call `super`, with either no args or passing explicit args. In your example, instead, you also call `const_missing(name)` and what will happen is that super will never be called because you will enter in a recursive loop where `const_missing` keeps calling itself.

The correct code is

```
  def self.const_missing(name)
    binding.pry
    super(name)
  end
```

which, in fact, triggers the error as expected

```
$ ruby test.rb
800
test.rb:9:in `class_eval': uninitialized constant TestClass::UNKOWNCONST (NameError)
```

Comment: Oh yeah I got super call mixed up with other languages. Thanks for the quick&clear answer!